# jquery ui tabs - is there a way to pass custom arguments to the event handler?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery

I am using jquery tabs to generate tabs for my page. 
On tab selection a event handler -

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
 // some code
});
```

I want to know of a way to pass my custom arguments to the event handler function. Or any other way by which I could send those arguments with 'ui' object or 'event' object.

Thanks
Saarthak

Comment: what kind of arguments do you want to send?

Comment: some values which will decide the way the content of the new tab will be managed.

Comment: well...you can always call your function with whatever arguments. I'm pretty sure this is not what you are after. Could you give some example code on what exactly you want happen? The code doesn't need to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer through jquery forum.

Posting it here for anyone looking for the answer -

You could use the event data mechanism of the bind function:

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', {abc: 'def'}, function(event, ui) {
      alert('here ' + event.data.abc);
});
```

Or just place your options in an accessible variable:

```
var tabOptions = {collapsible: true};
$('#tabs').tabs(tabOptions).bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
      alert('here ' + tabOptions.collapsibe);
});
```

Hope this helps someone.